# Whether the launchmode defined in Manifest override the launchmode called through intent flag or is it the other way around?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

### CASE I:- When the Intent Flag overrode the Manifest

In the manifest file, **I defined Activity_B as singleTop**.
These are the relevant lines in the manifest file:-

```
....
<activity android:name=".Activity_A" android:launchMode="standard">
...
<activity android:name=".Activity_B" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
<activity android:name=".Activity_C" android:launchMode="standard"/>
<activity android:name=".Activity_D" android:launchMode="standard"/>
....
```

The full manifest file is given below:-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activity_A" android:launchMode="standard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity_B" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activity_C" android:launchMode="standard"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activity_D" android:launchMode="standard"/>
</application>
```

**Now a method is created which sets the Activity_B as singleTask at runtime** the method is shown below:-

```
protected void startActivity(Activity activity, Class targetActivityClass){
    Intent intent=new Intent(activity,targetActivityClass);
    if(targetActivityClass.equals(Activity_B.class)) {
        getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Now when I ran this application **I noticed that the Intent flag overrides the launchmode in the manifest file.**

(*How I reached this conclusion:- Basically I noticed that when I go to Activity_B after launching several activities, the number of Activities got reduced which is a typical behavior of Single Task launchmode*)

### CASE II:- When the Manifest overrode the Intent Flag

**To confirm this** I changed the launchmode for Activity B to singleInstance in the manifest file and kept the launchmode as singleTask in IntentFlag.
**Now the launchmode of the manifest file was set as singleInstance**

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_B" android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

The **startActivity method remained same** i.e.

```
protected void startActivity(Activity activity, Class targetActivityClass){
Intent intent=new Intent(activity,targetActivityClass);
if(targetActivityClass.equals(Activity_B.class)) {
    getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

}

**This time, however, the manifest file was not overridden.**

(*How I reached this conclusion? The Activity C was not getting added to task containing Activity B which is the typical behavior of singleInstance launchmode.*)

I tried to find this in the documentation, but nothing was mentioned about this kind of behavior there. **Can anyone explain why the results in these two cases differ, what is happening, whether the launchmode defined in Manifest override the launchmode called through the intent flag or is it the other way around or there is some internal prioritization order of these launchmodes?**

*(This is my first question on StackOverflow, I apologize for any mistakes that I might have committed unintentionally)*

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain what is happening exactly whether the launchmode
>   defined in Manifest override the launchmode called through intent flag
>   or is it the other way around?

Flags defined through Intent during Activity start override the default mode from Manifest.

**Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#IntentFlagsForTasks):**

> When starting an activity, you can modify the default association of
>   an activity to its task by including flags in the intent that you
>   deliver to startActivity().

Following are the flags which can be used to modify the default behavior:

- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: First of all Thanks for answering my question
Yes, that's what I noticed when I ran the app with launchmode singleTop for Activity B in the manifest, and singleTask in the Intent Flag. But this behaviour changed when I ran the same app with launchmode single Instance in manifest. This time the single task launchmode overrided the manifest's singleInstance. I was unable to find the explainaition for this in the documentation. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Sankalp `Note: Some launch modes available for the manifest file are not available as flags for an intent and, likewise, some launch modes available as flags for an intent cannot be defined in the manifest.`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Based on your input I have categorized the question in two cases, What I am trying to ask is why the results in these two cases differ i.e. _(Case 1: When the Intent Flag overrode the Manifest and Case2:- When the Manifest overrode the Intent Flag)_  What I have inferred here is that there is some internal priority order assigned to launchmodes, however, this is just a hypothesis I was not able to verify this in the documentation. Can you please explain why these cases differ?

Comment: As observed, intent flags don't override singleInstance in manifest